# Beta Testing: Unable to download the app from playstore

Tags: android

I have an app in open beta release in Google playstore. I am able to download the beta app for android version 7+ but in android 6 devices even when I have the beta access I end up downloading only the previous production release app.

**NOTE:** Min Sdk for my app in Gradle file is 23 in production build and 21 in beta version. Version code of the app has been incremented over the previous version.

Is there anyone who has faced same/similar issue and if so how did you resolve it?

**Edit 1 :**
When I download the app in android 6 device I am ablke to see the (Beta) next to app name and the beta column in my app list menu , but when I open the app then it turns out to be the production build only.

Comment: Google Play store takes some time to reflect the updated changes. If that might be the case ?

Comment: @Nakul rightly said, but I am able to download the beta app in Android 7 and Android 8 devices. So I cannot fathom why in Android 6 device I cannot download the beta app.

Comment: will you be able to check if this is a device specific issue ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: @Nakul I have tested in 2 devices Galaxy On 5 and Moto G (3rd Gen) both were running on Android 6.0.1. I did not get any error while downloading or opening the app in both devices.